# Error in Cocoa-Touch with properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties

I have the following code (where an error appears):

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Unit : NSObject
{
    UIImageView *view;
    CGRect rect;
}

@property(readonly, assign) UIImageView *view;
@property(readwrite, assign) CGRect rect;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "Unit.h"
@implementation Unit

@synthesize view;  //Error appears here
@synthesize rect;

@end
```

The error that appears is `existing ivar 'view' for unsafe_unretained property 'view' must be __unsafe_unretained`. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should have a look into ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you have used (readonly, *assign*), however because you have also explicitly created the ivar, you need to add the `__unsafe_unretained` qualifier (due to *assign* qualifier) as per Automatic Reference Counting documentation on [property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Unit : NSObject
{
    CGRect rect;
}

@property(readonly, assign) UIImageView *view;
@property(readwrite, assign) CGRect rect;

@end
```

Simply remove the ivar declaration, and the compiler will generate the correct ownership qualifier.